# Story where the atmosphere is incinerated by a hail of micrometeorites. A "soft rain" I think

Tags: story-identification

Sorry, this is all I remember. A story where the end was a hail of micrometeorites all falling to Earth at once which incinerated the atmosphere from the collective heat from their re-entry. I think it was caused by either the moon being blown up or by a comet being destroyed by missiles.

I also think that it was called a "Soft Rain", but searching for a soft rain just gets me a different story about an automated house.

Any help on finding this story would be very much appreciated, this is one that's been on my mind for ages.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This would be *[Seveneves](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22816087-seveneves)* by Neal Stephenson.  The moon is blown to pieces by an unknown force, and the resulting rain of debris onto the atmosphere (termed "hard rain") sterilizes the Earth.  The first chapter was available to read online before the book was released, so you might just have read that part.

Comment: Hard Rain, Soft Rain, what's the difference? But in all seriousness thanks!

Comment: ...and thanks for finding me a book to read

Comment: Book about the end of human civilization as we know it. Currently at **666**14 ratings on the linked site.

Comment: The phrase "soft rains" has its origins in a poem by Sara Teasdale https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Will_Come_Soft_Rains, and it entered Sci-Fi in an end-of-human-civilization short story by Ray Bradbury which is the "automated house" story mentioned by the OP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Will_Come_Soft_Rains_(short_story).

Comment: @LeeMosher Google Ngrams shows fairly level usage of lower case "soft rains" back to about 1800:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soft+rains&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoft%20rains%3B%2Cc0 Capitalized "Soft Rains," which does appear to begin with Teasdale, is roughly comparable since 1920: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Soft+Rains&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSoft%20Rains%3B%2Cc0